# Use gulp for typescript compilation

Tags: javascript, typescript, gulp, angular

Following angular 2 quick start guide, guys there use typescript compiler and `tsconfig.json` file, to work with it. I was looking up ways to use gulp for this and indeed there seem to be ways to achieve this, however I'm a bit confused to correct implementation with angular 2.

essentially [gulp-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-typescript) and [gulp-tslint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-tslint) seem to be two plugins to achieve this and somehow `tsconfig.json` file is also in play here, although I don't grasp why.

Could anyone provide example for implementation that will achieve above? I believe all development .ts files should be within `src` folder and javascript needs to be pumped over to `build` folder. (assume for now that both folders have setup from [angular 2 quick start](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html))

Comment: [One of the most popular ng2 seed projects uses gulp](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed)

Comment: @drewmoore yeh I actually stumbled upon it, it has a lot going on there, where ass all I need is to set up a project with sass and ts support, hence this question, as I was not able to break up that seed repo to find these two things I need. And it lacks in explanation for me.

Comment: @Ilja My team used to use gulp with angular2 and sass, but there were always so many issues with getting all of the files into the streams, the project just couldn't grow naturally without a lot of maintenance. Just a friendly suggestion. Have you looked into using `npm` as your build process setting up an npm script in the package.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've setup gulp to work from `gulpfile.js/` **folder**. In this folder are `index.js`, `config.js` and `tasks/` folder, and in `tasks/typescript.js` is task that compiles TypeScript (tasks folder has 15 other tasks). So instead of one huge `gulpfile.js` I have manageable chunks that each do just one thing...

#### gulpfile.js/index.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var config = require('./config.js');
var plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
    plugins.brsync = require('browser-sync').create();
    plugins.builder = require('systemjs-builder');

function run(name) {
  return require('./tasks/' + name)(gulp, plugins, config);
}
// ...other tasks, in alphabetical order! (:
gulp.task('typescript',     run('typescript'));
```

#### gulpfile.js/config.js

```
var distDir           = 'dist';
var staticDir         = isGAE() ? '/static' : '';

module.exports = {
  SRC: {
    TYPESCRIPT:       'src/scripts/**/*.ts',
  },
  DST: {
    MAPS:                                   './maps',
    SCRIPTS:          distDir + staticDir + '/scripts',
  },
};
```

#### gulpfile.js/tasks/typescript.js

```
module.exports = function (gulp, plugins, CONFIG) {
  return function typescript() {

    var tsProject = plugins.typescript.createProject('tsconfig.json');
    var tsReporter = plugins.typescript.reporter.fullReporter();

    var stream = gulp
      .src(CONFIG.SRC.TYPESCRIPT, { since: gulp.lastRun('typescript') })
      .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.init())

      .pipe(plugins.typescript(tsProject, undefined, tsReporter))

      .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.write(CONFIG.DST.MAPS,
                                     {sourceMappingURLPrefix: '/scripts'}))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(CONFIG.DST.SCRIPTS))
      .on('error', plugins.util.log);

    return stream;
  };
};
```

#### gulpfile.js/tasks/watch.js

```
module.exports = function (gulp, plugins, CONFIG) {
  return function watch() {
    plugins.brsync.init(CONFIG.BRSYNC);

    gulp.watch(CONFIG.SRC.TEST,           () => queue_tasks(['karma']));
    gulp.watch(CONFIG.SRC.TYPESCRIPT,     () => queue_tasks(['typescript'], brsync_reload));
  };
};
```

I had an [issue with gulp watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32562563/gulp-watch-running-same-task-multiple-times-when-saving-many-files): if you're watching files, work on more then one file and save them all it will run a task multiple times, which can be annoying. Check the link for implementation of `queue_tasks()` function...

Also note that I'm using Gulp 4:

```
gulp.src(CONFIG.SRC.TYPESCRIPT, { since: gulp.lastRun('typescript') })
```

I've added in `src()` option `since` to cache files, and pass only changed files down the pipe. <strike>I implemented this just 2 days ago and didn't test it with typescript files (works in other places), so if there are issues just remove it...</strike>